# Select query to select from two tables

Tags: mysql, postgresql, select, join

I have two table in the PostgreSQL DB which looks like

```
 Select Productid,productname,quantity,availabilty  from public.product
```

And other table is

```
 Select sampleid,samplename,Productid from public.sample
```

So here I need to select the Products and their sample from the product table and sample table where Productid in the Product table is equal to the productid in the sample table. Should I be using the Joins here.I am confused with the Left and right join

Answer (score 0):

> I need to select the Products and their sample

I think you can use `LEFT JOIN` here to get all products and matching samples if any:

```
select p.*,
    s.sampleid,
    s.samplename
from public.product p
left join public.sample s on s.Productid = p.Productid;
```